# js time zone change

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I want to change the time zone to Karachi/Pakistan which is UTC +5. Please help I don't understand that what thing to change in this code. Here is the code:

```
var offset = moment().utcOffset();
var time = moment (time_utc).add({minutes:offset}).locale(locale);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change timezone in `momentjs` like follows.

```
moment(1369266934311).zone(-60).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm')
moment(1369266934311).zone('+0100').format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm')
```

To work with named timezones instead of numeric offsets, include Moment Timezone and use .tz() instead:

```
// determines the correct offset for Karachi/Pakistan at the given moment
moment(1369266934311).tz('Karachi/Pakistan').format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm')
```

for more examples,

```
var a = moment.tz("2013-11-18 11:55", "America/Toronto");
var b = moment.tz("May 12th 2014 8PM", "MMM Do YYYY hA", "America/Toronto");
var c = moment.tz(1403454068850, "America/Toronto");
a.format(); // 2013-11-18T11:55:00-05:00
b.format(); // 2014-05-12T20:00:00-04:00
c.format(); // 2014-06-22T12:21:08-04:00
```

You can find details [here](https://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/)